# Files not present in container after COPY or ADD in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a simple docker file that itself will launch a compose fleet. It may break the purpose of containers; but i found it was what I thought was the most suited in my case.

When trying to copy files to the image, it does not fail but I cannot find the files after run. I tried both ADD and COPY instructions. As seen in the example below, the docker-compose.yml and all my config files are not present in the container after launch. Can someone help with this ?

Here is my Dockerfile and the log it generates during image build and at container launch

```
FROM docker/compose

# Default user defined values
ENV TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
ENV PLAXDMIN_DNS="plaxdmin.default.org"

# Final values
ENV PLAXDMIN_VERSION="PL_V_PLACEHOLDER"


# Init folders and copy docker-compose api configuration files
WORKDIR /var/log/plaxdmin

WORKDIR /etc/plaxdmin
ADD ./resources/conf/* ./
RUN ls -al ./

WORKDIR /opt/plaxdmin/
ADD ./resources/docker-compose.yml ./
RUN ls -al ./

# Expose folders and port
EXPOSE 80

# On run debug and start compose fleet
CMD  docker -v \
    && docker-compose -v \
    && printenv \
    && ls -al /etc/plaxdmin \
    &&  ls -al /opt/plaxdmin/ \
    &&  ls -al /var/log/plaxdmin/ \
    && pwd \
    && whoami \
    && docker-compose up
```

```
plaxdmin_1   | Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
plaxdmin_1   | docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d3
plaxdmin_1   | HOSTNAME=2bf446fc73cb
plaxdmin_1   | SHLVL=2
plaxdmin_1   | HOME=/root
plaxdmin_1   | PGID=1421
plaxdmin_1   | TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
plaxdmin_1   | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
plaxdmin_1   | PLAXDMIN_DNS=plaxdmin.vba.ovh
plaxdmin_1   | PUID=1421
plaxdmin_1   | PWD=/opt/plaxdmin
plaxdmin_1   | PLAXDMIN_VERSION=v-202101312014-alpha
plaxdmin_1   | total 8
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 31 17:59 .
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 31 20:26 ..
plaxdmin_1   | total 12
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jan 31 19:34 .
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 31 20:15 ..
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Jan 31 19:34 portainer
plaxdmin_1   | total 8
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 31 17:59 .
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 31 20:15 ..
plaxdmin_1   | /opt/plaxdmin
plaxdmin_1   | root
plaxdmin_1   | 
plaxdmin_1   |         Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
plaxdmin_1   |         parent. Are you in the right directory?
plaxdmin_1   | 
plaxdmin_1   |         Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
plaxdmin_1   |         
appdata_plaxdmin_1 exited with code 1
```

EDIT :
To explain my main goal more clearly, I need to develop an app that run as a SINGLE service among others in a compose file. My app is divided in docker containers (api, web client, discord client, database, proxy, more to come).
So my code is organized as a meta topp repository having all other repos as git submodule. When I commit the meta project, it triggers the build/publish of every child image on dockerhub. Then the meta project build an image that runs all this sub images/containers in a compose file. The Dockerfile you're seeing above is for that meta project.

EDIT 2:
Update dockerfile that contains error. And adding the docker build output.

```
Step 1/13 : FROM docker/compose
latest: Pulling from docker/compose
aad63a933944: Pulling fs layer
b396cd7cbac4: Pulling fs layer
0426ec0ed60a: Pulling fs layer
9ac2a98ece5b: Pulling fs layer
9ac2a98ece5b: Waiting
b396cd7cbac4: Verifying Checksum
b396cd7cbac4: Download complete
aad63a933944: Verifying Checksum
aad63a933944: Download complete
0426ec0ed60a: Verifying Checksum
0426ec0ed60a: Download complete
9ac2a98ece5b: Verifying Checksum
9ac2a98ece5b: Download complete
aad63a933944: Pull complete
b396cd7cbac4: Pull complete
0426ec0ed60a: Pull complete
9ac2a98ece5b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b60a020c0f68047b353a4a747f27f5e5ddb17116b7b018762edfb6f7a6439a82
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker/compose:latest
 ---> c3e188a6b38f
Step 2/13 : ENV TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
 ---> Running in 313daae863cf
Removing intermediate container 313daae863cf
 ---> d0dd8c94b9e3
Step 3/13 : ENV PLAXDMIN_DNS="plaxdmin.default.org"
 ---> Running in dbd36e109d3f
Removing intermediate container dbd36e109d3f
 ---> 5df13f4aec2c
Step 4/13 : ENV PLAXDMIN_VERSION="v-202101312014-alpha"
 ---> Running in 9085c5958ae5
Removing intermediate container 9085c5958ae5
 ---> 8b16db353f10
Step 5/13 : WORKDIR /var/log/plaxdmin
 ---> Running in 2f3dd94d0e75
Removing intermediate container 2f3dd94d0e75
 ---> d228994e7927
Step 6/13 : WORKDIR /etc/plaxdmin
 ---> Running in 92f3713bd54c
Removing intermediate container 92f3713bd54c
 ---> ef7a8736ba0b
Step 7/13 : ADD ./resources/conf/* ./
 ---> ee36033c9c5e
Step 8/13 : RUN ls -al ./
 ---> Running in 60bb92954ecf
total 20
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 31 20:15 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 31 20:15 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           262 Jan 31 02:06 application.properties
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           690 Jan 31 02:06 log4j.properties
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1518 Jan 31 19:31 nginx.conf
Removing intermediate container 60bb92954ecf
 ---> c794e76b2cb3
Step 9/13 : WORKDIR /opt/plaxdmin/
 ---> Running in bf6ed28a47a8
Removing intermediate container bf6ed28a47a8
 ---> e2dcd4913ea3
Step 10/13 : ADD ./resources/docker-compose.yml ./
 ---> 1346e4e2d930
Step 11/13 : RUN ls -al ./
 ---> Running in 5ddbbe7f440f
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 31 20:15 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 31 20:15 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          2317 Jan 31 19:31 docker-compose.yml
Removing intermediate container 5ddbbe7f440f
 ---> f3013003a8ea
Step 12/13 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 229fc6cdbfe1
Removing intermediate container 229fc6cdbfe1
 ---> 21189a057021
Step 13/13 : CMD  docker -v     && docker-compose -v     && printenv     && ls -al /etc/plaxdmin     &&  ls -al /opt/plaxdmin/     &&  ls -al /var/log/plaxdmin/     && pwd     && whoami     && docker-compose up
 ---> Running in 9265e36232c1
Removing intermediate container 9265e36232c1
 ---> d94ccaeebf34
Successfully built d94ccaeebf34
Successfully tagged plaxdmin/full:v-202101312014-alpha
```

Comment: Were these files present in your current directory at the moment you built the image?

Comment: The Dockerfile you show doesn't `COPY` anything into `/etc/plaxdmin`; should it?

Comment: (It looks like you're trying to create a container of config files that will get mounted into the created containers.  The Compose `volumes:` option either refers to Docker named volumes or directories on the physical host; you can't mount files directly from one container to another.  I can't tell if this will be a problem for your final setup.)

Comment: @tekki: yes. I guess otherwise the build would not succeed.

Comment: @david it supposed to via (`COPY resources/conf/* ./`).No ? Also my setup is like this:
UNRAID as physical server that runs a VM with all my services via docker compose. The Dockerfile above is to add all my app componenets (api, db, ect) as only one service in the VM's compose file.

Comment: You set `WORKDIR /var/log/plaxdmin` immediately before that line.

Comment: That is only to create that folder and make sure it is present in the container. I switch those two paths; my mistake. But I have the same problem with the other COPY in the /opt folder. (I also edit my post to explain more of my main goal in case it makes things clearer)

Comment: [SOLVED] I ran that image via a compose file; in it i mapped those folder for them to be accessible in their parent. I tried to remove those and it works now; but how can I make those folder expose the configurations files to the parent ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran that image via a compose file; in it I mapped those folder for them to be accessible in their parent as volumes. I tried to remove those and it works now.

I'm not sure this is the final solution as I have [other troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65996347/couldnt-connect-to-docker-daemon-at-httpdocker-localhost-is-it-running-s) now as I need those files at least readable from the host but that is a problem for later?