# Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running? (special use case)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I guess you all know this error pretty good. In order to understand why I may encouter it, you may need some background info about the context as it's not really a common use (i think at least).

1. I have an UNRAID server
2. A VM running in this server
3. A bunch of services running in containers via compose in this VM (referenced later as my production VM)
4. [PROBLEM] I need to add a container that itself will run compose from [this official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose)

This last container is maintained by myself and should run an API, web client, db, ect. When building it I first trigger the build of proxy, api, web and other project that I develop and once ot's done I build the compose one from the images I just built and some open source ones.

To test I created a dummy VM on my unraid server and created a compose environment similar to my production VM. (let's call it my test VM). I added a compose file with only my app and portainer.

The problem is when I run 'docker-compose up' on that test server, portainer start but my app fails because it cannot connect to it's docker daemon (see logs below)

What I tried:

- running my app as root or a created user
- adding the created user to docker group (but docker group does not exists so I'm creating it; seems odd to me...)
- checking permission on `/var/run/docker.sock`: it returned a file not found error even as root
- passing the socket from my test VM when running the parent compose via a volume (`- "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"`)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker/compose

# Create plaxdmin user
RUN adduser plaxdmin --disabled-password
RUN addgroup docker
RUN addgroup plaxdmin docker
USER plaxdmin


# Final values
ARG PLAXDMIN_VERSION
ARG RELEASE_TYPE
ENV PLAXDMIN_VERSION=$PLAXDMIN_VERSION
ENV RELEASE_TYPE=$RELEASE_TYPE

# Default user defined values
ENV TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
ENV PLAXDMIN_DNS="plaxdmin.default.org"


# Init folders and copy docker-compose api configuration files
WORKDIR /var/log/plaxdmin

WORKDIR /etc/plaxdmin
ADD ./resources/conf/* ./

WORKDIR /opt/plaxdmin/
ADD ./resources/docker-compose.yml ./


# Expose port
EXPOSE 80


# On run debug and start compose fleet
CMD    docker -v \
    && docker-compose -v \
    && printenv \
    && ls -al /etc/plaxdmin \
    && ls -al /opt/plaxdmin/ \
    && ls -al /var/log/plaxdmin/ \
    && pwd \
    && whoami \
    && groups $user \
#    && ls -la /var/run/docker.sock \
    && docker-compose up || true
```

docker build logs:

```
Step 1/18 : FROM docker/compose
latest: Pulling from docker/compose
aad63a933944: Pulling fs layer
b396cd7cbac4: Pulling fs layer
0426ec0ed60a: Pulling fs layer
9ac2a98ece5b: Pulling fs layer
9ac2a98ece5b: Waiting
b396cd7cbac4: Verifying Checksum
b396cd7cbac4: Download complete
aad63a933944: Verifying Checksum
aad63a933944: Download complete
aad63a933944: Pull complete
0426ec0ed60a: Verifying Checksum
0426ec0ed60a: Download complete
b396cd7cbac4: Pull complete
9ac2a98ece5b: Verifying Checksum
9ac2a98ece5b: Download complete
0426ec0ed60a: Pull complete
9ac2a98ece5b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b60a020c0f68047b353a4a747f27f5e5ddb17116b7b018762edfb6f7a6439a82
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker/compose:latest
 ---> c3e188a6b38f
Step 2/18 : RUN adduser plaxdmin --disabled-password
 ---> Running in 07aa9a297234
Removing intermediate container 07aa9a297234
 ---> 494c8a4291e0
Step 3/18 : RUN addgroup docker
 ---> Running in f64e5022e65d
Removing intermediate container f64e5022e65d
 ---> 84ee5fbf6dea
Step 4/18 : RUN addgroup plaxdmin docker
 ---> Running in 0efa66b73f4a
Removing intermediate container 0efa66b73f4a
 ---> eb647c03c118
Step 5/18 : USER plaxdmin
 ---> Running in 4529203341d1
Removing intermediate container 4529203341d1
 ---> 8501d9993307
Step 6/18 : ARG PLAXDMIN_VERSION
 ---> Running in 07d61186fadd
Removing intermediate container 07d61186fadd
 ---> ed6e9f9df0ab
Step 7/18 : ARG RELEASE_TYPE
 ---> Running in 0fa98c641843
Removing intermediate container 0fa98c641843
 ---> d0fe2f700e53
Step 8/18 : ENV TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
 ---> Running in 5c5d383c6858
Removing intermediate container 5c5d383c6858
 ---> 48394a4e01b3
Step 9/18 : ENV PLAXDMIN_DNS="plaxdmin.default.org"
 ---> Running in 187304a8a1ed
Removing intermediate container 187304a8a1ed
 ---> 5827abebd0ff
Step 10/18 : ENV PLAXDMIN_VERSION=$PLAXDMIN_VERSION
 ---> Running in 54ff13db32e6
Removing intermediate container 54ff13db32e6
 ---> 9377ac82544e
Step 11/18 : ENV RELEASE_TYPE=$RELEASE_TYPE
 ---> Running in 2da68d0375ac
Removing intermediate container 2da68d0375ac
 ---> dd09ee57c867
Step 12/18 : WORKDIR /var/log/plaxdmin
 ---> Running in 9ac2fdb93c5e
Removing intermediate container 9ac2fdb93c5e
 ---> 252771ee5ff4
Step 13/18 : WORKDIR /etc/plaxdmin
 ---> Running in eb6c9a16b12f
Removing intermediate container eb6c9a16b12f
 ---> 6fd180adcb80
Step 14/18 : ADD ./resources/conf/* ./
 ---> 70e10c126b4f
Step 15/18 : WORKDIR /opt/plaxdmin/
 ---> Running in 0a6f15afc915
Removing intermediate container 0a6f15afc915
 ---> d8c321d31689
Step 16/18 : ADD ./resources/docker-compose.yml ./
 ---> 60847c38d0be
Step 17/18 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in cbe2a4d7f8be
Removing intermediate container cbe2a4d7f8be
 ---> 56269d51e6d5
Step 18/18 : CMD    docker -v     && docker-compose -v     && printenv     && ls -al /etc/plaxdmin     && ls -al /opt/plaxdmin/     && ls -al /var/log/plaxdmin/     && pwd     && whoami     && groups $user     && docker-compose up || true
 ---> Running in 49d1a3505198
Removing intermediate container 49d1a3505198
 ---> beba0e2fd039
Successfully built beba0e2fd039
Successfully tagged plaxdmin/full:latest
Successfully tagged plaxdmin/full:unstable
Successfully tagged plaxdmin/full:v-202102010319
Successfully tagged plaxdmin/full:64ce4f02f88ac81219dd61ae0d8c2e4aa6e0403e
Successfully tagged plaxdmin/full:master
```

Start logs:

```
plaxdmin_1   | Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
plaxdmin_1   | docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d3
plaxdmin_1   | HOSTNAME=b3a358707bd6
plaxdmin_1   | SHLVL=2
plaxdmin_1   | HOME=/home/plaxdmin
plaxdmin_1   | PGID=1421
plaxdmin_1   | TIMEZONE=Europe/Paris
plaxdmin_1   | RELEASE_TYPE=unstable
plaxdmin_1   | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
plaxdmin_1   | PLAXDMIN_DNS=plaxdmin.vba.ovh
plaxdmin_1   | PUID=1421
plaxdmin_1   | PWD=/opt/plaxdmin
plaxdmin_1   | PLAXDMIN_VERSION=v-202102010319
plaxdmin_1   | total 20
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  1 15:57 .
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  1 15:59 ..
plaxdmin_1   | -rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           262 Jan 31 02:06 application.properties
plaxdmin_1   | -rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           690 Jan 31 02:06 log4j.properties
plaxdmin_1   | -rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1518 Jan 31 19:31 nginx.conf
plaxdmin_1   | total 12
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  1 15:57 .
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  1 15:57 ..
plaxdmin_1   | -rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          2374 Feb  1 02:01 docker-compose.yml
plaxdmin_1   | total 8
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Feb  1 15:57 .
plaxdmin_1   | drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  1 15:57 ..
plaxdmin_1   | /opt/plaxdmin
plaxdmin_1   | plaxdmin
plaxdmin_1   | plaxdmin docker
plaxdmin_1   | Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?
plaxdmin_1   | 
plaxdmin_1   | If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the goal of your container is to run Docker commands, it has permissions to take over the entire host system should it choose to.  It's not any less safe to run it as `USER root`, which will also address the socket permission problem.  Since your Dockerfile doesn't actually do anything switched to the alternate user (`COPY` makes files be owned by root by default and you do not `RUN` any commands) you can also delete the `USER` line and the alternate-user setup.

```sh
# This user and group will not be used; delete these lines
# RUN adduser plaxdmin --disabled-password
# RUN addgroup docker
# RUN addgroup plaxdmin docker

# Nothing is done as this user
# Stay as the default root user to be able to run `docker` commands
# USER plaxdmin
```

If the host's `/var/run/docker.sock` is mode 0660 and owned by a group `docker` (a typical setup) the container process must run as the same *numeric* group ID in order to be able to access the socket.  This will intrinsically be host-specific and it's not something you can set in your Dockerfile.

When you launch the orchestration container, you can [run it with an additional group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups) to put it in the `docker` group

```sh
# If the container process isn't already running as root
docker run \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --group-add docker \
  ...
```

Or, in Compose version 2 syntax (but not version 3) there is a [`group_add:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#group_add) option that can specify this

```yaml
version: '2.4'
services:
  orchestrator:
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    group_add:
      - docker
```

(The documentation says the group must exist in both contexts, so you may need to [look up the numeric group ID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639990/what-is-the-group-id-of-this-group-name) and use that instead.)

Comment: > which will also address the socket permission problem - 
Actually id does not; as said in my original question I tried it with root. |

What I don't understand is why do I have to pass the socket from the host to the orchestrator ? Can't my orchestrator have it's own ?

Comment: [SOLVED] Ok, so I guess in my dozens of different tries, i forgot to try running as root AND passing the socket from the host. It works without messing with any user or group. Thanks a lot !!!  But my last question still remains; Can't my orchestrator have it's own socket ?

Comment: No, because it needs to talk to the host's Docker daemon.  The bind mount is the only (safe) way to make it accessible to the container.  Running a separate Docker daemon inside the container is theoretically possible, but generally discouraged, and leads to some confusing questions about which Docker exactly you're talking to.